# grep/list bash recursive

Tags: bash, grep

```
parts = grep "/root/backups/*"

for part in $parts
do
    echo $part
    rm -rf $part #delete
done
```

I basically need to iterate through a folder and return every item in the folder using a Bash script.

Unable to get working via grep, although may be a much simpler way. First line is pure pseudo-no-clue-code.

Comment: You can use find if I'm understanding what you need to do it's simply... find /root/backup/*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be done without looping.

If you just want to get rid of the files, just use rm:

```
$ rm -rf /root/backups/*
```

If you want to show the filenames as you delete them, use find instead:

```
$ find /root/backups -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The -maxdepth option tells find to not descend any further than one level from the starting point, /root/backups.  The -mindepth option tells find where to start returning results, effectively telling find to ignore the the starting point.  The -print option just prints the found files to the screen.  With the -exec, the {} are replaced with the found files, so this calls rm to delete them.

EDIT: eliminated an unnecessary -exec per comment

Comment: Would -print and -delete work in place of your -exec's?

Comment: You could use -print to replace the first -exec, but -delete will not work on directories that are not already empty.  I think you'll still need the second -exec.

Answer (score 1):

Change the grep command to:

> for i in ``ls -bRC1 /path/*  ; do echo $i ; rm $i ; done

The -b will escape spaces and other characters that may result in errors and unintended consequences with the rm. -R is recursive.  -C1 is single column (which may be redundant). I would reconsider the -rf

You may want to use find instead of a for loop

`find /path -H -maxdepth 3 -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \; -ls`

If you don't know what the above options mean, type `man find`.

Comment: `for i in /path/*` does everything except the recursion and works with filenames that have spaces. Here is some information regarding [avoiding parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0):

grep -l will give you just the filenames

parts = grep -rl ....

Comment: `grep` is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: i presumed there is some content he wants to look into it - yes grep is not doing any good

Answer (score 0):

You want a list of file names in a given directory. There is a program that does this, and you be embarrassed to read it's name: `ls`. Thats all it does! You want a recursive listing including files in subdirectories, so use `ls -R`. You can put the output of that into a variable in your script and do as you please with it.